# simple comparison script doesnt seem to work

Tags: javascript, comparison-operators

I keep getting a syntax error caused by the final else statement at the end of the script. This seems to stop anymore JS running on the page, but I can't figure out why it's causing an error. More than likely, it's a really simple syntax thing that I just can't see, because I've been looking at it too long. If anyone could help that would be great. I've declared the variables in the code, but in the actual program these are based on other conditions and will be integers.

```js
var nbdJDay = 70;
var mmWindow = 1;
var dayCompare = nbdJDay;
if (dayCompare < 85 && dayCompare > 14) {
  mmWindow = 2;
} else if (dayCompare < 15 && dayCompare > -15) {
  mmWindow = 3;
} else {
  mmWindow = 0;
}
```

Comment: where are the semi-colons of statements after if else's :o Are you drunk :P :D

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code, the syntax error must be somewhere else

Comment: The semicolon is not breaking anything and that fragment should work fine, problem is likely elsewhere

Comment: okay. what syntax error comes?

Comment: How are you editing/running your files? Are you using an IDE, syntax checker, etc. Rather than fix your code for you, please you could post your error so that we can explain the error to you.

Comment: @evolutionxbox It appears you've edited the code so that the problem goes away?

Comment: @RowlandShaw I just removed the final `;`, which should have no effect on the operation of the script, and put the code inside a "snippet".

Comment: @evolutionxbox and added the other semicolons... Either way, the snippet doesn't reproduce the behaviour the original poster is asking about

Comment: bizarrely enough removing the final ";" seems to have fixed it! I've got a load more script above this snippit so im guessing that was causing a conflict. what a headache! anyways thanks for the help, glad its sorted.

Comment: @danish443 not drunk, just a REALLY bad programmer! :)

Comment: @RowlandShaw Whoops. Didn't mean to fix the problem in the question.